# How do I add wordings in Flash's right-click panel?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called `contextmenu` take a look at this tutorial **[Customizing Flash Context Menu](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/contextmenu/)**

[image]

Comment: The question is tagged 'actionscript-3', this appears to be an as2 tutorial?